# How to get square brackets in apa citation on overleaf?

Tags: citing, apa-style, overleaf

The title pretty much sums up my entire problem. Right now the cited source just appears as plain text behind what I have written, which is highly disruptive to the reading flow. I would like to have square brackets around the source to indicate that it isn't part of the text. Furthermore what my supervisor wants me to use is the apalike 2 style, which doesn't seem to exsist on overleaf.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Have you googled `bibliographystyle`? The following might be insightful: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related. I hope you find the answer!